# disabling image selection in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with images loaded in it, when I tap on the image sometimes it has a grayish highlight on the image/image border. How do I disable this when I click/tap on the image? Do I have to do this via javascript?

Comment: Do you need user interaction on any part of the webview other than image ?

Comment: yes I actually need user interaction.. I just don't want that shaded grayed frame to appear when I press on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is a link, the below function may be helpful.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    return NO;
}
```

You can also look into this function.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: that's not what I want.. I am already doing that so that it doesn't open the link. What I want is to disable the selection that occurs when I tap on the image.. the shaded grayed frame that you see when you click on the image

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable links only

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {



        return NO;

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your js:

document.documentElement.style.webkitTapHighlightColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
   document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";